# Postfix Conditional redirects

Tags: postfix, email-server, zimbra, milter

I have a tricky one here!

I have a dinamic list of some... 3000 email addresses that I need to filter on Postfix.

I need that if any of these addresses sends an email to (support@mydomain.com or priority@mydomain.com) the email gets redirected to **low-prio@mydomain.com** and put it into a folder named **inbox/lowprio**

I cant use just header checks, because, all mail from this users would be treated.
So I am guessing that I need a header check that forwards the process to a milter that finishes it.

**The concept in my mind goes like this:**

**Header Checks:**

```
TO:^(.*)support@mydomain.com FILTER relay:[127.0.0.1]:10027
TO:^(.*)priority@mydomain.com FILTER relay:[127.0.0.1]:10027
```

**In Master.cf create the filter that will catch the flow:**

```
[127.0.0.1]:10027   inet  n       n       n       -       0       spawn
    user=nobody argv=/usr/local/mail_filter.pl
```

In the Perl file, get the {mail_addr} and if it is in the list, exit with a REDIRECT command.
Maybe also APPEND a Header like: **X-final-folder : Inbox/lowprio**

This Header, would allow a Sieve to catch it and move the mail into the specified folder...

I am really struggling with this, so any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: From what I can see, the following will likely be your best bet: http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html The following page is where I grabbed this from:
http://mattshaw.org/news/how-to-filter-mail-with-postfix-header_checks/ You might also look at the following:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231232/postfix-filter-incoming-mails-based-on-mail-from-and-rcpt-to

Comment: Not really, everytime you use header checks, it will be applied to all accounts. I need the FORWARD action with 2 conditions as explained.

Comment: this could be a good approach : https://serverfault.com/questions/688489/postfix-conditional-header-checks