# SMTP header rewrite rules

Tags: postfix, smtp

We have an SMTP relay (postfix) where we need to rewrite headers on the fly based on certain criteria:

*if> header contains **x-custom-header: type 1***
*and if> **to: @customer1.com***
*rewrite> **from: `<no-reply@mycompany.com>`** to **from: Friendly Name `<friendly@mycompany.com>`***

Currently I'm using 3 instances of [postmulti](http://www.postfix.org/postmulti.1.html) just for once client, with a header_check for each component of the ruleset.

But this approach will spawn / require a new instance for each rule due to restrictions in postfix where you can't have a header check for both a TO and FROM field in the same rule.

Question is: how do I scale this in an effective manner? Is there a better way to format / utilize the header checks.

Or are there alternative systems to easily manage advanced rulesets for header rewrites in an SMTP relay, like maybe through a gui?

Requirements will be to have multiple rules for at least three x-custom-headers with multiple clients.

Postfix Config:
***Instance 1***

```
#main.cf instance 1:
...
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
multi_instance_wrapper = ${command_directory}/postmulti -p --
multi_instance_enable = yes
multi_instance_directories = /etc/postfix-instance2 /etc/postfix-instance3
...
```

```
#header_checks instance 1
/^x-custom-header: type 1/ FILTER smtp:127.0.0.1:10025
#need to add this next /^x-custom-header: type 2/ FILTER smtp:127.0.0.1:10026
#need to add this next /^x-custom-header: type 3/ FILTER smtp:127.0.0.1:10027
```

***Instance 2***

```
#master.cf instance 2
127.0.0.1:10025      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

```
#main.cf instance 2
...
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-instance2
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix-instance2
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix-instance2/header_checks
multi_instance_name = postfix-instance2
multi_instance_enable = yes
...
```

```
#header_checks instance 2
/^To: (.*)@customer1.com/ FILTER smtp:127.0.0.1:10028
```

***Instance 3***

```
#master.cf instance 3
127.0.0.1:10028      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

```
#main.cf instance 3
...
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix-instance3
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix-instance3
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix-instance3/header_checks
multi_instance_name = postfix-instance3
multi_instance_enable = yes
...
```

```
#header_checks instance 3
^From: (.*?)@mycompany.com/ REPLACE From: Friendly Name <friendly@mycompany.com>
```

Comment: Do you have any examples on how you would use that for the scenario described? The milter documentation is a bit of a heavy read and haven't encountered that before..

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach using [postfix pipe](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) to a script as suggested in some of these resources:

- https://thecodingmachine.io/triggering-a-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-a-mail
- http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Conditional-sender-rewrite-based-on-recipient-address-td93497.html

and just because I ran into this issue trying to avoid a loop:

- [Specifying a Postfix Instance to send outbound email](https://serverfault.com/questions/599140/specifying-a-postfix-instance-to-send-outbound-email)
- http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html

For my default-postfix's master.cf

`external   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
        flags=Fq user=mail null_sender= argv=/opt/scripts/external.sh ${recipient} ${domain} ${sender}`

Second instance's main.cf I had to add `authorized_submit_users = mailuser` and in master.cf I'm listening on a separate port `127.0.0.1:10025      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd`

Then I'm still busy writing the logic for the bash script, but I think I will use the same approach as [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/688489/postfix-conditional-header-checks), but nost notably is the sendmail command to use the second instance `/usr/sbin/sendmail -G -i -t -C /etc/postfix-sender/main.cf`